# PHP not displaying data

Tags: php, mysql

Any ideas why this simple php code won't display results when trying to echo the data.

```
<?php
        {
            mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


            $pid=intval($_SESSION["User_id"]); 
            $query = "SELECT `car`, `details`, `price` FROM `Car``";

            //executes query on the database
            $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

            //this selects the results as rows
            $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    


            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

                $_SESSION['car'] = $row['car'];
                $_SESSION['details'] = $row['details'];
                $_SESSION['price'] = $row['price'];
            }
        }
        ?>  

        <?php echo $_SESSION['car']; ?>
        <?php echo $_SESSION['details']; ?>
        <?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?>
```

Just testing at the moment to see if the car, price and details display from the database and they don't seem to.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_ functions because they are deprecated. Use pdo instead.

Comment: Are the quotes inside the query going the correct direction? Looks like they are copy/paste characters that are not quotes

Comment: @JayRizzi, yeah it is going to the right place

Comment: Oh, there may be some issue with $_SESSION not showing immediately the values, some reason i recall having proba with that a while ago...is the only problem that the session doesnt store the values, or that the query just wont return, like if you changed the rows to just echo rather than session storage, are you getting results?

Comment: @JayRizzi, the query won't return. It just displays login. I have used $_SESSION on other application, can't figure out why it won't work on here

Comment: Can you post some more code? I am not sure what just displaying login refers to

Comment: Enable error reporting first; put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I rather remove all backticks since non of those identifiers are reserved keywords.

```
$query = "SELECT car, details, price FROM Car";
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `session_start();` at start of page and change

```
$query = "SELECT `car`, `details`, `price` FROM `Car``";
                                                     ^
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT `car`, `details`, `price` FROM `Car`";
```

Comment: Tried that. It just displays login

Comment: And i have got session start at the top

Comment: @user2236990 Can you describe `It just displays login`?

Comment: Yeah, basically when i visit that specific php page (car.php) it simply displays login in the middle of the page instead of car details

Comment: @user2236990 Show your full code. Whatever you have posted it's impossible to know where is problem. In your posted code we have solved your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting one or many results for this query ?
If many results, you are saving the last entry in the session.
If only one, just do : $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) instead of this while.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query.Try to echo it, copy, paste in MySQL and run it. But you have `$pid`, have you put it in the query?

`$query = "SELECT car, details, price FROM Car WHERE id = $pid ";`